# What are the differences in the disassembly of two .NET executables built from the same source code?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

Set up:

- same source code is used build a .NET 4 executable (console application) on two different machines.
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1 .NET 4 settings are identical on the two machines
- `ildasm projectName.exe /out:test.txt` is performed on the .exe's from both machines.
- ildasm output differs beyond expected differences (mvid, privateimplementationdetails).

Question:
     I have spent some time creating an application to get the CRC of a .NET executable and have succeeded in ignoring all differing build-time data.

I am removing all data above the `// =============== CLASS MEMBERS DECLARATION ===================` line in ildasm.exe output. This ignores the MVID. I am building the .exe without debug information. And lastly, I parse the output for `<PrivateImplementationDetails>{GUID}` and ignore those.

I then CRC the remaining text file.

The CRCs are the same when the same project is built on the same computer, but differ when the same project is built on a different computer with identical source code and MSVS 2010 settings.

Does anyone know of any machine-dependent information stored in the assembly of a .NET executable?

Below is an example of the differences. It appears that different IDs are being assigned each object and class, but I find it odd that this would only differ when they code is build on different machines...

```
         `class DSC_PI.MainWindow/'<>c__DisplayClass21' V_2,`
         `class DSC_PI.MainWindow/'<>c__DisplayClass10' V_2,`  

         `class DSC_PI.MainWindow/'<>c__DisplayClass1e' V_3,`
         `class DSC_PI.MainWindow/'<>c__DisplayClassd' V_3,`
```

Any insight would be much much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that both systems have the same service packs installed, including the same versions of all the .NET assemblies in the GAC? Are you doing a full rebuild from a clean directory that contains source code only? I've run into similar odd problems when older versions of assemblies are left lying around in bin and obj directories.

Comment: Hmm, thank you. I will look into those but I feel like this unexpected hitch might just be overlooked as we will be using one "master build machine" to build and crc everything. Crisis averted there, but I am still interested in figuring them out. Unfortunately I might just have to leave this problem behind and move on (been working on this little thing for a long time now...). I will keep this updated if I find anything new though.

Comment: I would suggest, when you get to the "master build machine" that you use MSBUILD to do your builds from the command line rather than using Visual Studio. I've had much better luck getting reproducible results with MSBUILD. Plus, it's easier to automate.

Comment: thank you very much, I will mention that to my higher-ups :)

Comment: Are both machines running the same OS with the same updates installed?There are several parts of the C# compiler that are known to be non-deterministic; the fact that you are consistently getting the exact same results on the same machine is more a coincidence than anything else. Is there a reason why it matters whether compiler-generated identifiers are identical across machines?

Comment: About the coincidence, I "delete" the randomly generated MSIL data and store everything else in a file that I use for comparison. The identifiers don't have to be the same across all machines because we're going to use only one to generate CRCs. (though at the time of this question that wasn't established)

Comment: The compiler most likely uses some kind of seed for generating the compiler-generated classes/code. Many compilers rely on the fact that 2 consecutive builds (same code, same machine) will have different internal code. Not sure what the reason for C# to have this though.

Answer (score 1):

Do both systems have the same number of cores? I could imagine, that when it comes to counting up the variable name suffix, the result can differ depending on the number of threads used for the compiler.